# Spring Boot application failed. localhost is malformed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have basic spring boot application with spring cloud. When i tried to run i have error:

```
2020-02-27 18:52:29.542 ERROR [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "http://localhost:8445" is malformed
```

Why does it happen? And how to fix it?

Comment: Try changing `port` in properties file. If issue persists, provide complete stacktrace

Comment: this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703383/java-net-malformedurlexception-unknown-protocol-localhost-at-controller-restco

Comment: Provide complete stack trace.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/grcvNb3d

Comment: Can you post feign client configuration?

Comment: feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 5000
        readTimeout: 120000

Comment: Post Interface code and application properties both.

Comment: URL: "http://localhost:8445"

Comment: @FeignClient(name = "instrument", url = "${URL}", path = "instrument_tag")
public interface Instrument

Answer (score 1):

I hope you got the solution but this will help others.

When we add property values in the spring boot application.properties file that should be without double quotes(""). if you mention in double quotes it will throw an exception.

```
payment.host="http://localhost:9090"
```

this will throw

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "http://localhost:9090" is malformed
```

but when we remove double quotes application will run without any error.

```
payment.host=http://localhost:9090
```

Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path